# What does asynchronous stack unwinding mean?

Tags: multithreading, common-lisp, sbcl

Here is a part of the doc of `sb-thread:terminate-thread`:

> The unwind caused by TERMINATE-THREAD is asynchronous, meaning that
>   eg. thread executing
>
> ```
>   (let (foo)
>      (unwind-protect
>          (progn
>             (setf foo (get-foo))
>             (work-on-foo foo))
>        (when foo
>          ;; An interrupt occurring inside the cleanup clause
>          ;; will cause cleanups from the current UNWIND-PROTECT
>          ;; to be dropped.
>          (release-foo foo))))
> ```
>
> might miss calling RELEASE-FOO despite GET-FOO having returned true if
>   the interrupt occurs inside the cleanup clause, eg. during execution
>   of RELEASE-FOO.

Documentation is written in a way that it seems that async stack unwinding means that thread termination can occur at the moment when the thread executes cleanup clause of `unwind-protect`, causing some parts of the cleanup clause to be not executed.

Is async stack unwinding exactly this thing or am I missing something? This definition doesn't really match my current background in asynchronous programming.

Comment: Yes, asynchronous operations can happen at any unpredictable point in the normal execution of the program. Say you have threads `A` and `B`. If `A` calls `TERMINATE-THREAD` on `B`, whatever `B` happens to be doing at the moment is interrupted with the instruction to terminate itself. You could use `SB-SYS:WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS` to prevent the interruption at certain parts of the program, but otherwise there is no way to predict when the order to terminate will arrive.

Answer (score 0):

in this context, "asynchronous" means "another thread does something without regard for what the target thread is doing." specifically, an asynchronous unwind will interrupt the target thread in the middle of whatever it is doing (unless a `without-interrupts` form is in effect), even if "whatever it is doing" is installing an `unwind-protect` barrier. the documentation is describing a class of bugs where a thread `target` allocates some resource (operation A), then installs an `unwind-protect` barrier to deallocate that resource (operation B), then works with it (operation C), while another thread `killer` attempts to terminate `target`. if `killer` catches `target` in the moment after allocating the resource but before installing the `unwind-protect` barrier, the resource will never be deallocated. the `target` code that does this might look like:

```lisp
(let ((some-resource (allocate-resource)) ; operation a, allocate SOME-RESOURCE
  ;; if you get interrupted right here, SOME-RESOURCE is never freed
  (unwind-protect ; operation b, install a barrier to deallocate SOME-RESOURCE
      ;; if you get interrupted in here, you're fine
      (work-with-resource some-resouce) ; operation c, work with SOME-RESOURCE
    (deallocate-resource some-resource) ; the deallocator installed by operation b
```

the manual has a reasonable description of how to prevent these bugs; you use `without-interrupts` around allocating your resource (A) and installing its `unwind-protect` barrier (B) to ensure that you aren't interrupted between the two, and then use `allow-with-interrupts` around the body (C) to respond to terminate when it's safe again. the fixed `target` code might look like:

```lisp
(sb-sys:without-interrupts
  (let ((some-resource (allocate-resource)))
    ;; we can't be interrupted here, because we're between WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS
    ;; and ALLOW-WITH-INTERRUPTS
    (unwind-protect
        (sb-sys:allow-with-interrupts
          ;; now that we've entered the UNWIND-PROTECT, our barrier is installed,
          ;; so if we get terminated, SOME-RESOURCE will be freed during the unwind.
          (work-with-resource some-resource)
      (deallocate-resource some-resource))))
```